# How to write routing and app.js correctly in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to know how to write `routing` in Node.js

now that in my `router`

```
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render("index");
});
router.get('/quiz',(req,res)=>{
    res.render("quiz");
});
```

now that in my `app.js`

```
app.use('/', Router);
app.use('/quiz',Router);
```

When I trid to change `app.js`

```
app.use('/', Router);
```

This work well.

But I change `app.js` like following

```
app.use('/quiz'.Router);
```

I accessed`/`,then I get`quiz.ejs`,my expectation is to get`index.ejs`

What happend?

and I'd like to understand the relation in `app.js`and`router`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

so app.use is a middleware so whenever you make a get request the app.js start running by order trying to reach the exact same router or we call it End point , in your case this `app.use('/quiz'.Router);` the params is not correct as the first arg is the path of the route/Endpoint and there's no secound one which tell which res file should i get , so it will pass it until it reach the second one which is ending with / also  that's why it got you to `router.get('/quiz',(req,res)=>{ res.render("quiz"); });`

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why when I write `app.use('/', Router);` in `app.js` and then access`/quiz`, `quiz.ejs` was displayed. which is another endpoint of `/` why this work well in this case ... thanks.

Comment: it depends on the order of the middle wares " route"  and which one you call it , first one to match will use it